# Couldn't run Flutter application on BlueStacks simulator

Tags: flutter, adb, simulator, bluestacks

I am using BlueStacks v.3 as Android simulator for my Flutter project, I could connect Android Studio to BlueStacks with adb.exe command: `adb connect localhost:5555` but when I run the project, application does not open on the simulator.
Whats is the reason and how it can be solved?

Comment: did you test Genymotion?

Comment: No, BlueStacks is more flexible and consumes less RAM and CPU resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of rendering type of BlueStacks and can be solved by running the following command in Android Studio terminal:

```
flutter run --enable-software-rendering
```